# The Docs Versions Table Should Give Better Guidance

Tags: feature-request, documentation, versions

So there I was editing the Versions section of the [Google Visualization Docs Page](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/google-visualization). Got down all my version info, formatted the table all nice, clicked on save as this was the last section, and whammo!

> [image: Why do you tell me now?]

There are three problems with this message:

1. The guidance for how to format this section disappeared as soon as I started typing
2. The guidance that disappeared didn't explain this limitation
3. Redoing tables written with `|` is not very fun

#### Guidance Disappears

This is the only guidance you get:

> [image: Thanks Grey Text!]

Unfortunately, as soon as you start typing, it disappears. This means that to review the limited guidance you have to select all, cut, read, and re-paste. And pray that you don't get distracted elsewhere and use your clipboard.

#### Guidance Doesn't Explain the Rules

I assumed I could make any table I wanted -- nothing told me I couldn't. What does it matter, after all, which column the date is in?

#### Redoing it Hurts

That table looks something like:

```
Version | Release Date | Syntax for Selecting this Version |
------- | ------------ | --------------------------------- |
Current | February 23, 2016 | `google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});` |
44 | February 23, 2016 | `google.charts.load('44', {packages: ['corechart']});` |
43 | October 2, 2015 | `google.charts.load('43', {packages: ['corechart']});` |
...
```

Changing the date format is relatively easy. Moving them around? Thank goodness I didn't add more columns.

#### Proposed Solution

If Versions are going to be one of the first ways that people interact with documentation, they should be more user-friendly.

1. If there is an error, it should be detected on the first row so they can adjust before they've done the rest of the table (something like *"Please use yyyy-mm-dd date formats in the last column"* if they either don't have something that fits that format, or if it isn't in the last column)
2. If that isn't doable, the system should just automatically move their dates to the last column without asking (since we've parsed it and we know what they're giving, just sort it out so they don't have to)

Since Versions is the last section you touch for the first request on the docs, it's the last thing after (hopefully) a bunch of thought on how to introduce a language and its key topics. That means a bunch of work has gone in to creating something, and to be unable to save that because of an error that requires busywork to solve is incredibly frustrating at a point where it makes us more likely to lose a valuable contribution.

At the very least we need to let folks save with this so we can fix it later -- it shouldn't stop folks from saving their contributions.

Comment: Just curious, can you submit it if you have the table like: `|name|Syntax|release date|`, like a sandwich? The rules seem to indicate it is OK, but they're confusing, I agree.

Comment: @Laurel yes you can